# Type error: done is not a function (nodemailer)

Tags: node.js, smtp, mailgun, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer for a forgot password app, the email executes for the forgot password, but when the user resets their password they don't get a confirmation email. not sure why that's not happening.

seems to be throwing an error on the done(err) line. below is the get handler for the reset token

```
//get handler for reset token
app.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                    req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
                    return res.redirect('back');
                }

                user.password = req.body.password;
                user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

                user.save(function(err) {
                    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                        done(err, user);
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        function (token, user, done) {
            var options = {
                service: 'Mailgun',
                auth: {
                    user: 'postmaster@Sandboxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org',
                    pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                }
            };
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport(options))

            var mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'postmaster@Sandbox65b418bcf76c4a5e909aedb7b6e87b45.mailgun.org',
                subject: 'Your password has been changed',
                text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
                'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
            };
            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                req.flash('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
                done(err);
            });
        }
    ], function(err) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're incorrectly calling `done` function in the first waterwall task. The second task is expected two parameters: `token, user` and additional callback. But you pass only one parameter: `user`.

Add `token` parameter in `done` function:

```
 ...
 user.save(function(err) {
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
       done(err, token, user); // TODO: initialize token
    });
});
....
```